# Docker/alpine: How to install nodeJS 4.8.4 at alpine image

Tags: node.js, docker, alpine-linux

I am using `alpine` (min. 3.5) and I need to use nodeJS 4.8.4

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM alpine:3.5
RUN apk add --update nodejs=4.8.4 ffmpeg graphicsmagick
```

But this gives me the error

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
nodejs-6.9.5-r1:
breaks: world[nodejs=4.8.4]
The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --update nodejs=4.8.4 ffmpeg graphicsmagick' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

How do I install nodeJS in version 4.8.4 using alpine?

Comment: Have you tried using https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/4.8/alpine/Dockerfile with just the first line changed to `alpine:3.5` and your own packages added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two alternatives:

1. Using the alpine 3.5 image, build nodejs from source
2. Use the node:4.8.4-alpine then update it to alpine 3.6

Here is how the first Dockerfile would look(copied straight from the official image):

```
FROM alpine:3.5

ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL info
ENV NODE_VERSION 4.8.4

RUN addgroup -g 1000 node \
    && adduser -u 1000 -G node -s /bin/sh -D node \
    && apk add --no-cache \
        libstdc++ \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        binutils-gold \
        curl \
        g++ \
        gcc \
        gnupg \
        libgcc \
        linux-headers \
        make \
        python \
  # gpg keys listed at https://github.com/nodejs/node#release-team
  && for key in \
    9554F04D7259F04124DE6B476D5A82AC7E37093B \
    94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5 \
    FD3A5288F042B6850C66B31F09FE44734EB7990E \
    71DCFD284A79C3B38668286BC97EC7A07EDE3FC1 \
    DD8F2338BAE7501E3DD5AC78C273792F7D83545D \
    B9AE9905FFD7803F25714661B63B535A4C206CA9 \
    C4F0DFFF4E8C1A8236409D08E73BC641CC11F4C8 \
    56730D5401028683275BD23C23EFEFE93C4CFFFE \
  ; do \
    gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --keyserver keyserver.pgp.com --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key" ; \
  done \
    && curl -SLO "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION.tar.xz" \
    && curl -SLO --compressed "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/SHASUMS256.txt.asc" \
    && gpg --batch --decrypt --output SHASUMS256.txt SHASUMS256.txt.asc \
    && grep " node-v$NODE_VERSION.tar.xz\$" SHASUMS256.txt | sha256sum -c - \
    && tar -xf "node-v$NODE_VERSION.tar.xz" \
    && cd "node-v$NODE_VERSION" \
    && ./configure \
    && make -j$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN) \
    && make install \
    && apk del .build-deps \
    && cd .. \
    && rm -Rf "node-v$NODE_VERSION" \
    && rm "node-v$NODE_VERSION.tar.xz" SHASUMS256.txt.asc SHASUMS256.txt

ENV YARN_VERSION 0.24.4

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps-yarn curl gnupg tar \
  && for key in \
    6A010C5166006599AA17F08146C2130DFD2497F5 \
  ; do \
    gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --keyserver keyserver.pgp.com --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key" ; \
  done \
  && curl -fSLO --compressed "https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/$YARN_VERSION/yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz" \
  && curl -fSLO --compressed "https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/$YARN_VERSION/yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz.asc" \
  && gpg --batch --verify yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz.asc yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz \
  && mkdir -p /opt/yarn \
  && tar -xzf yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz -C /opt/yarn --strip-components=1 \
  && ln -s /opt/yarn/bin/yarn /usr/local/bin/yarn \
  && ln -s /opt/yarn/bin/yarn /usr/local/bin/yarnpkg \
  && rm yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz.asc yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz \
  && apk del .build-deps-yarn

CMD [ "node" ]
```

Or for the second alternative

```
  FROM node:4.8.4-alpine
  RUN  sed -i -e 's/v4\.4/v3.5/g' /etc/apk/repositories \
       && apk update \
       && apk add --upgrade apk-tools \
       && apk upgrade --available \
       && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

The benefit of compiling your own binary is that the overall image will have less of a hierarchy (it will depend on alpine 3.5 only) while the second image will depend on node:argon-alpine which depends on alpine 3.4 but is technically an alpine 3.5 but the second image will indeed be faster to build since the compilation will already have been done

Answer (score 0):

use `FROM node:4.8.4-alpine` image this will give you nodejs with alpine flavour this saves you time and is much easier than installing the node inside alpine
https://hub.docker.com/_/node/

Comment: No, as node:4.8.4-alpine is using alpine 3.4, which doesn't support graphicsmagick out of the box. Therefor alpine 3.5 is needed...

Comment: then your question needs to be `how to install graphicsmagick with node 4.8.4 in apline ? ` not `How do I install nodeJS in version 4.8.4 using alpine?`